# Beautiful Soup lower-casing tags by default?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am using LXML with Beautiful Soup. I have an XML document that has upper-case tags. When I use `BeautifulSoup`, it seems to lower-case the tag names which makes my use of `find_all` un-intuitive. Does BS actually do this, or is something else going on?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(
    markup= data
    features= 'lxml', # 'html5lib', # 'html.parser',  #'lxml', #xml
    )
soup.find_all('SEC-HEADER') # Returns nothing
soup.find_all('sec-header') # Returns data
```

I see the [explainer here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#other-parser-problems), however I thought the LXML parser would ensure it preserved case.

> Because HTML tags and attributes are case-insensitive, all three HTML
> parsers convert tag and attribute names to lowercase. That is, the
> markup  is converted to . If you want to
> preserve mixed-case or uppercase tags and attributes, you’ll need to
> parse the document as XML.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I did not read [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) thoroughly enough. `lxml` is actually an HTML parser, which does not maintain case. The *actual* XML parser is `xml`.